# Hair Dynamics throwing hair all over the place in Blender 2.8

Tags: particles, hair

Hair particles are bouncing all over the place with Hair Dynamics turned on. I have seen other forums where they all had different solutions. Such as turning up the quality steps and others that I tried. None of these solutions worked for me. I am trying to simulate the hair that would follow a horses hair path with maybe a light breeze as he is walking. I came closer to the tail than I did with the mane. The tail I turned down the gravity settings in the field weights to .68 and increased the density target in the hair dynamics settings to 6.0 and the density strength up to one. Then increased the stiffness to 3.0 and the mass to 1kg. However by about frame 6 it starts dancing all over the place. These settings did not work at all on the mane. I uploaded the scene file and a screen shot in case anyone can have a look.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijdrtszrcsgifbf/hair_test.blend?dl=0

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If I cannot figure it out I am just going to use corrective shape keys for the hair particle system.

Comment: Or maybe not, I guess that feature was removed. I thought I would be able to apply the shape key to the emitter and it would still work but from what I read it will not.

Comment: Or I can use shape keys, but I have to use strips of game hair for the tail at least and distort everything else to make it look like it is animated and then use shape keys.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if you already figured this out, but when the hair is going all over the place, if you want the hair to move together like a head of hair or like a main, you need to set the voxel size high enough, 1.0 is a good start, and then set the hair target hair density to 0.5, and target strength to something like 0.01.  Goal strength i set to 0.3 for cloth and for hair.  That should get you going in the right direction.

Under field weights wind can be an issue, OH and your hair may to heavy at 0.3kg, try 0.08 kg to start, maybe less.